# C++ Reading from a File, Writing, Deleting and Updating. A little assistance?

Tags: c++, file

I'm writing a virtual ATM program which can create accounts, update balance, withdraw money and check balance, etc. As of now I have completed all the functions that check balance and withdraw money etc. I can't seem to figure out the fstream file processing part.

How do I implement the code such that the program writes to, reads from a file called "accounts.txt" and displays the 
Name:
Account No:
Balance:
Contact Info:

and also update balance, since withdrawal and addition of cash updates the balance

I'm new to C++ and still trying to grasp C++ concepts.

Let me know if you need any more information on the program.

Thanks in advance, sir/madam :)

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff and file handling.  You might want to try this in a language like Ruby or Python before messing with C++

Comment: It's a self-experiment assignment in C++. It definitely has to be C++ :)

Comment: it will be more easy if you use a database for this task. something like sqlite will be easy to handle. this is the correct method of doing such tasks..... :)

Comment: There's a lot of examples here in the internet on how to do the basic reading and writing in C++. The only thing you need to know is how to get the values within it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a structure for account with all the details.
Then do file operations using the structure like blocks.

```
struct accounts
{
    char name[20];
    long accno;
    int balance;
    long contact;
};
```

Call function

```
writeData(string fileName)
{
    ..get input
    accounts acc;
    int block_size=sizeof(acc);
    fstream foo("accounts.txt", ios::out|ios::app); 
    foo.write(acc,block_size);
    foo.close();
}
```

Reading would be similar

For withdrawl & deposit (Updating balance):

Use two members one for reading and one for getting user input.
Then using account number as identifier, search through and update records.
Use `tellp()` to get position for matching record.
Then you could use `seekp()` to move in a file.
Writing the same structure when keeping the file pointer at the beginning will overwrite the record in a file.

Answer (score 0):

First, declare an fstream object and initialize it with the file "account.txt", along with specification that you want to read and write into the file. That will require you to use the ios static variables.
You need to look into them. 
This will open your file for reading and writing,
you can read information  and either overwrite to the same file or append the new information to the file.
I just did all this a few months ago and I used the book by Deitel. It was great help. 
http://www.cppforschool.com/tutorial/Files1.html

This link also holds examples that youmay want to look into.